# Grouping Steps in Buildbot

Tags: python, buildbot

I have a set of steps that are logically grouped together, and should all be skipped based on a property set by the user. I know that I can skip certain steps individually by setting the doStepIf parameter, but I was wondering if there was a way to group them all and skip that group somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I think I had a similar issue, so I created a trigger with doStepIf, and the triggered item had multiple steps.

```
factory_neo_modules_common_build.addSteps(common_factory_cbi_steps_debug)
factory_neo_modules_common_build.addStep(
    Trigger( schedulerNames=['modules_other test trigger'],
             waitForFinish=True,
             flunkOnFailure=False,
             doStepIf=CheckNativeBuilder ) )
```

Comment: I was hoping that there would be a way to do it without having to set up another scheduler. This looks like it might be the only way to do this though.